# Different results from PHP's driver and MongoDB console when using $near

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm getting different results depending on where I ask from.  I have a Mongo collection "stops" indexed by 2d co-ordinates.

From the Mongo Console:

```
> db.stops.find({loc:{$near: [-##.94248402000001,##.444653126]}}).limit(3)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e8e0e64597535e4cb0001bd"), "stop_id" : 873198944, "stop_name" : "STOP ONE", "loc" : [ -##.942535, ##.444538 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e8e0e66597535e4cb001260"), "stop_id" : 1603800857, "stop_name" : "STOP TWO", "loc" : [ -##.94355, ##.444672 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e8e0e66597535e4cb000bb7"), "stop_id" : 3659710794, "stop_name" : "STOP THREE", "loc" : [ -##.94355, ##.444672 ] }
```

My PHP code:

```
$mdb=new Mongo();
$result=$mdb->myapp->stops->find(array('loc'=>array('$near'=>array(floatval($this->userLongitude),floatval($this->userLatitude)))))->limit(3);
```

I'm new to Mongo, but I'm pretty sure that code is right.  It returns values... just, the wrong ones.  Here's what `var_dump(iterator_to_array($result));` outputs:

```
array
    '4e8e0e67597535e4cb002092' => 
        array
        'stop_id' => float 373055431
        'stop_name' => string 'STOP A' (length=34)
        'loc' => 
        array
            0 => float -##.937874
            1 => float ##.442722
    '4e8e0e64597535e4cb00022d' => 
        array
        'stop_id' => float 4245689695
        'stop_name' => string 'STOP B' (length=32)
        'loc' => 
        array
            0 => float -##.937515
            1 => float ##.442692
    '4e8e0e67597535e4cb0020af' => 
        array
        'stop_id' => float 134217173
        'stop_name' => string 'STOP C' (length=21)
        'loc' => 
        array
            0 => float -##.938965
            1 => float ##.443787
```

Everything is in [longitude,latitude] format, like the Mongo docs say to do.  I don't know what is causing the different results, except for maybe I've botch the PHP query, but it's returning data.  What's wrong?

*I've stripped out the IDs for brevity and changed some of the data that shouldn't matter except for privacy (namely, the ## hide the degrees and the stop names are different— if it's critical to see those, I can edit it, but everything else is untouched.)*

**EDIT:Solved**
My code to filter/parse longitude and latitude was also truncating the co-ordinates to only two decimals places.  When I used the console directly, there wasn't any truncation going on.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but could this be because you have 64bit version of MongoDB and 32bit version of php? I'm probably wrong, since you using all floats and not integers but still something to suspect.

Comment: what does var_dump of `array('loc'=>array('$near'=>array(floatval($this->userLongitude),floatval($this->userLatitude))))` return ?

Comment: @Mechcozmo You should add your answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem existed in my PHP code.  My own fault.  See the edit in the original question.